# Is it possible to use a P4 command to `Mark for Delete` every file that is "missing"?

Tags: perforce

Say I had checked in the files:

- a.txt
- b.txt
- c.txt

I checked them all out so that I could mass edit them by dumping files from another folder:

`cp -R folder-one/* folder-two/`

The result is:

- a.txt (updated)
- b.txt (deleted)
- c.txt (no changes)

Now I `Revert Unchanged Files` and intend to submit:

- a.txt (updated)
- b.txt (deleted)

But I can't because now `b.txt` is "missing".

Is it possible to use a P4 command to `Mark for Delete` every file that is "missing"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest fix is just to revert all of the files that you've opened (with the `-k` flag so you keep your local changes) and let `reconcile` figure it out from square one:

```
p4 revert -k ...
p4 reconcile ...
```

Comment: In the future you can just skip the `p4 edit` and `p4 revert -k` steps and do `cp -f` followed directly by `p4 reconcile` :)